# I am stock on this validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

I want to make this validation rule where every time assignment__C is active then the disable_date_c must be blank. So if it shows some date the validation rule shows the error message. This is what I got so far but I am missing something.

```
AND(
    ISBLANK(Disable_Date__c)    
    ISPICKVAL(assignment__c,"active"),
)
```

Comment: What happens?  Does it just not work the way you want?  That exact validation rule won't even save...

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules will display an error when the formula evaluats to true.

In your case, you want the validation rule to be true when the `assignment__c` field is 'active' and the `disable_date__c` field is not blank.

i.e.

```
AND(
  NOT(ISBLANK(disable_date__c)),
  ISPICKVAL(assignment__c, 'active')
)
```

When troubleshooting things like validation rules, workflow rules, etc. it's a good idea to isolate the conditions.  In this case, if you'd changed it the just be `ISBLANK(disable_date__c)`, it would immediately show up that the logic was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the formula by Nick with time assignment  as a checkbox and got an error when time active was checked and disable date was not blank.

```
AND(time_active__c==TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK(Disable_Date__c))).
```